# Determine the z parameters of two port network

Tags: network, port

New to EE, and I was wondering if anyone could help me check what is wrong with my answer on this question.
[image]

$$\frac{V1-Vn}{4}+\frac{V2-Vn}{3}=\frac{Vn-4V1}{2}$$
$$Vn=\frac{-27}{13}V1-\frac{4}{13}V2  -(1)$$
$$I1+\frac{V2-Vn}{2}=\frac{Vn-4V1}{2}, I1=\frac{Vn-4V1}{2}-(\frac{V2-Vn}{2})   -(2)$$
$$I2+\frac{V1-Vn}{4}=\frac{Vn-4V1}{2}, I2=\frac{Vn-4V1}{2}-(\frac{V1-Vn}{4})   -(3)$$
Subbing equation 1 into 2 and 3, I got I1= -2V1+0.5V2, which does not correspond to -2 and -2/3.

Any idea why? Thanks

EDIT to response:

Hi there, thanks for your response.
Unfortunately, I don't quite get your explanation. From my notes:
[image]
[image]

It seems as though they wanted me to use nodal analysis to solve this problem, hence my workings as followed.
For example,
[image]

Hence I am still unclear/unsure of your suggested solution. Pardon for being a newbie at this just started my first-year course for EE.

Comment: Edited my answer, what I meant was V1 and V2 respectively

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going about this haphazardly - consider a very simple two port network and it's formulas as shown below: -

[image]

Look at the impedance term in the top left (R1 + R2). It basically tells you this: -

$$V_{IN} = I_{IN}\cdot (R1 + R2)$$

So, in your circuit (with the dependent source) you have to find the equivalent i.e. what is \$I_{IN}\$ based on the input \$V_{IN}\$. Simple observation will tell you that \$I_{IN}\$ is: -

$$\dfrac{-(4Ω + 2Ω)}{3\cdot V_{IN}} = \dfrac{-2}{V_{IN}}$$

So the impedance is -2Ω in the top left position.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi there, edited my original post to respond to you :)

Comment: I'm struggling to think how I could explain it in a simpler manner. Also, why did you switch to Y parameters in your edit. I don't think it matters but it confuses me as to where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Oh, the Y parameters were an example from my notes. From what I understand for Z parameters, its simply finding V1 and V2 in terms of I1 and I2 right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Eq.(1) has got the signs wrong. It should be

   ```
   Vn = (27/13)V1 + (4/13)V2
   ```
2. Ohm's law to 4 ohms resistor gives you

   ```
           I1 = (V1 - Vn)/4 = V1/4 - Vn/4
              = V1/(4) - (1/4)[(27/13)V1 + (4/13)V2]
              = (-7/26)V1 - (1/13)V2                     (*)
   ```
3. Ohm's to 3 ohms resistor gives you

   ```
           I2 = (V2 - Vn)/3 = V2/(3) - Vn/3
                            = V2/(3) - (1/3)[(27/13)V1 +(4/13)V2]
                            = (-9/13)V1 +(3/13)V2        (**)
   ```
4. Express as matrix equation

   ```
   [I] = [Y][V}
   ```

   Then,

   ```
   [Z] = Inv [Y]
   ```
5. Would have been easier if you apply KVL to input port and output port separately to get the matrix equation

   ```
   [V] = [Z][I].
   ```